# How to open and run an exported JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

While watching a tutorial on YouTube, the creator exports a Java JAR file and opens it which runs his created app. When I attempt to repeat the process, it just opens the content of the JAR.

[image: my attempt]

[image: What the creator did.]

Comment: And get rid of Win-Rar, 7-zip is so way more better as I see you're using the eval version and it has the annoying - *buy me!*

Comment: jar files are zip files with optional extra rules.  Therefore it makes sense for an over-eager archive viewer to "grab" the jar file type for it self.

Comment: Prospeed-orginal - if any of the two answers helped you and I am sure they did - please be sure to select one of them as "the answer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your computer is configured to open JAR files with WinRAR.

You can change this by going to Control Panel > Default Programs

Set java as the program to open JAR files.

Alternatively you can open a cmd window or PowerShell window and type the command

```
java -jar <path to your JAR file>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you, but how do I select "Java"?

Comment: Nevermind that it works, however when I try to open the files with Java a black screen appears and disappears and nothing happens. How do I solve that?

Comment: @Propseed if you use the alternative method I suggested, i.e. open a window and enter the command, then you may get some error message displayed which may help to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your jar file is being opened in winrar by default. right click on your jar and from `open with...` choose java to run the jar